# How to delete a newline within a string

Tags: c, string

I want to delete a Newline '\n' within a string.

```
 char *string ="hallo\n";

    int i=0;
    int length = sizeof(string);

    while(i<length)
    {
        if(string[i+1] == '\n')
        {
            string[i+1] = '\0';
            break;
        }   
        i++;
    }

    printf("%s",string);
    printf("world");
```

I know that I could just spawn a new array and it works like this

```
char *string ="hallo\n";

int i=0;
int length = sizeof(string);
int lengthNew = length -1;
 char newStr[lengthNew];
    while(i<length)
    {
        printf("Char ist %c:",string[i]);
        newStr[i] = string[i];
        if(string[i+1] == '\n')
            break;
        i++;
    }
```

But why using stack if I just could substitude one character in the old array?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there is only one single newline in your string, and that it appears at the end?

Comment: is the `\n` character always at the end of your string?  Or can it be in the middle?  (e.g., `"hello\nworld"`)

Comment: yes... it's actually for the ctime(&clock)

Comment: Your `sizeof` calls don't do what you think they do. Use `strlen` to get the lenght of a null-terminated string. `sizeof` will return the size of the pointer in this case. Also, it is likely that you cannot modify string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the newline is always the last character of the string, you could code it like you have described.

Otherwise you'd have to create a second character buffer and copy the characters to the second buffer. The reason for this is that in C the `\0` character marks the end of the string.

If you have a string like this: `"this \n is \n a \n test"`, then after your replacement the memory would look like this: `"this \0 is \0 a \0 test"`. Most C programs will simply interpret this as the string `"this "` and ignore everything after the first null.

**EDIT**
As other have pointed out, there are also other problems with your code. sizeof() will return the size of the character pointer, not the length of the string. It is also not possible to modify a readonly string literal.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment, I offer a completely different, yet better solution: [`strftime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime):

```
time_t clock = time(NULL);

char buf[1024];

strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%c", localtime(&clock);

printf("The date is: %s\n", buf);
```

The `%c` format is the same as is used by `ctime`, but `strftime` is more flexible.

Answer (score -2):

```
char *string = ctime(&myTimeT);
char *c = strrchr(string, '\n');

if (c != NULL)
    *(c) = '\0';
```

Comment: This will only find the *last* occurrence of `\n`, and you are just plopping a NULL terminator into an arbitrary position in the string. -1

Comment: OP specifically said in a comment that it was for removing the `\n` at the end of a string returned by `ctime` (i.e., non-const and with a single `\n` at the end).

Comment: You're right, I didn't see that comment.  Your solution still modifies a readonly string however, so I can't remove the downvote until you remove the UB.  Also, if the newline is always the last character there is no need to use `strrchr` at all.

Comment: makes sense to me.  Out of curiosity, what's UB stand for?

Comment: Undefined behavior.  You are modifying a string literal which is readonly.  The declaration of `string` should be `const char *string = "hello\n"`.  If you want a mutable string declare it as `char string[] = "hello\n"`. (or dynamically allocate it)